# 1066, "Not unique table/alias - mysql query

Tags: python, mysql, join

I have the following query

```
'''SELECT %(t1)s.*, %(t2)s.id, %(t2)s.street 
   FROM %(t1)s, %(t2)s 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN %(t2)s 
   ON %(t2)s.id = %(t1)s.location_id 
''' % { 't1' : 'table1', 't2' : 'table2' }
```

I have tried using `LEFT OUTER JOIN %(t2)s t2alias ON t2alias.id = ...` but to no avail. Instead I get a `1054, "Unknown column`. What am I missing?

thx

Comment: Hm, if I look at your query I see no point in `JOIN`-ing `table2` twice?

Comment: What is `%(t1)s`?  Why can't you just do `table1.*` or give aliases like `FROM table1 alias1, table2 alias1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see your problem:

```
SELECT %(t1)s.*, %(t2)s.id, %(t2)s.street
FROM %(t1)s, %(t2)s 
             ^^^^^^ Already declared in the LEFT OUTER JOIN
LEFT OUTER JOIN %(t2)s
ON %(t2)s.id = %(t1)s.location_id
```

Try removing the `, %(t2)s` from the `FROM` line; it's enough to have it in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You have `table2 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2`.  I think you just mean to do:

```
FROM %(t1)s,
LEFT OUTER JOIN %(t2)s
```

I also think it's an odd practice not to specify the table names in the query.  If they change frequently that would *also* be weird to me.